# adding dropdown to bootstrap menu when using a specific template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

im using a template called ruma that uses bootstrap I have only used the navbar from the template and have tried various ways of adding a navbar. None of the other questions on here seem to answer my needs.

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="border-bottom:none !important;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">JACOB PUNTON</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="index">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-selected"><a href="services">SERVICES</a>
     </li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

That's my HTML and i need to add a dropdown under services. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there what you need to do is add a class of dropdown to your list element you can do it like so

```
  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you head to the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) you'll see an example of the full, default code for a `dropdown-menu` in a `navbar`. See example snippet below.

```
<li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">DROPDOWN <span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="border-bottom:none !important;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">JACOB PUNTON</a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-selected"><a href="services">SERVICES</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">DROPDOWN <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```